# Confluent Schema Registry Compatibility Modes for JSON Schema

Tags: apache-kafka, jsonschema, confluent-schema-registry

I am planning to register KafkaJsonSchemaSerializer with my KafkaProducer to send JSON serialized messages to Kafka. According to the [documentation](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/schema-registry/fundamentals/serdes-develop/serdes-json.html#:%7E:text=The%20following%20additional%20configurations%20are%20available%20for%20JSON%20Schemas%20derived%20from%20Java%20objects%3A) I understand the serializer will derive the schema from my java objects.

Considering there are 3 compatibility types that the Schema Registry can enforce (Backward, Forward and Full), i do not understand how will this work for Json Schemas that are automatically derived from java objects. More exactly i do not understand how is derived if a field is considered optional or not.

For example in Full mode, documentation says:
"Changes allowed: Add or Delete optional fields"

How will Schema Registry know if a field is optional or not?

Answer (score 0):

> How will Schema Registry know if a field is optional or not

From the schema. See docs about `json.oneof.for.nullables` property.

> Json Schemas that are automatically derived from java objects

I do not believe this is automatic. With Avro or Protobuf, for example, schema definitions are embedded within the generated classes. With JSONSchema, reflection may be used to create the schema, otherwise, as the documentation shows, you can provide `@io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.annotations.Schema` annotation on the class.

Compatibilty mode is never "derived". The registry starts with a default mode, which you can override per subject.

Also see the blog post in the [Related Content](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/schema-registry/fundamentals/serdes-develop/serdes-json.html#related-content)

Comment: hi! thanks for the answer but i am still a bit confused. you say "I do not believe this is automatic." and then "With JSONSchema, reflection may be used to create the schema". So is the schema derived/constructed automatically based on the Java class or not? and if it is, what criteria does it uses to identify nullable vs non-nullable fields? For the cases in which you specify the schema explicitly i understand how it works, that is clear. I am just wondering for the cases in which you do NOT specify the JSONSchema yourself, but just provide the java class.

Comment: Jackson itself uses reflection. But the documentation shows adding a whole annotation manually, was my point. I'm not sure what's required or not. For anything else, A `String` field, for example, can be null. An `int`, `boolean` cannot. `Integer` and `Boolean` objects can... Lists and arrays can... There's also a `@NonNull` or `@JsonProperty(required=true)` annotations that might help. But basically any non primitive can be null. Otherwise, as I answered, you can set `json.oneof.for.nullables=false`